# Solr - Sort 0 values at end

Tags: solr

I want to sort a distance field in ascending order. Some of the records have a value of 0 for the distance. This field isn't null, it's actually equal to 0. I want to sort these records in ascending order by distance, while keeping the ones with a value of 0 at the end of the results. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: Setting the value of the distance field to something high like 999999 is not an option because the farthest that the user can search is 200km, meaning that if I set it to 999999km, it will never show.

Answer (score 0):

use a function query, for example, if your fields is called 'distance':

```
&sort=if(eq(distance,0),0,div(1,field(distance))) desc
```

check function queries' doc [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery)